# Timer Job to send email at days end (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, list, email, timer-jobs

Can anyone tell me if a timer job can be set up to send an email at the end of each day if a new entry/entries is made to a submission page? I want it to notify the intended person if they get new entries once a day, and how many new entries they have.

Comment: can you add more description? your actual requirement is confusing. Do you want to know how to trigger timer job end of the day or others?

Comment: http://www.sharepointviking.com/a-sharepoint-2010-timer-job-example-with-e-mail-notification/

Comment: yes. I need to know how to set up a timer job, and have it trigger at the end of the day to email a specific person (based on what the submission was) but I only want it to email them if there is a new submission(s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using a SharePoint 2010 Custom timer job. Refer the below link for the steps to create a custom timer job programmatically.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403323/SharePoint-Create-Custom-Timer-Jobs

In the example given in the above link, the time job has been scheduled to run for every five seconds using `SPMinuteSchedule` class. To make your timer job run at the end of every day you may use the code given below which uses `SPDailySchedule` class,

```
SPDailySchedule dailySchedule = new SPDailySchedule(); 
dailySchedule.BeginHour = 21; 
dailySchedule.BeginMinute = 0; 
dailySchedule.BeginSecond = 0;
```

The above code schedules the timer job to run every day at 9PM. For more details refer the below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spdailyschedule_properties.aspx